# Get screen width and height in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I extend activity in my app I can get width and height:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

or

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
stageWidth = display.getWidth();
stageHeight = display.getHeigth();
```

But at  present I extend fragment and I can't use the above code to get the width.

Comment: did you solved your question ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try below modifed code of yours

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

or

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int stageWidth = display.getWidth();
int stageHeight = display.getHeight();
```

Basically you just required to put `getActivity()` (to get the context) before `getWindowManager()` function.

Comment: `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are now deprecated. Also, here's another way:

`Point size = new Point();

getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);`

Answer (score 10):

This will give you what you want without needing for context or view:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;

int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Comment: This simple method if you don't want to support Multi-window. 
When it comes to Multi-window and you need screen width (of your app) then you need to get it through context.

Answer (score 6):

This code also works with Fragments:

```
int width = getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
int height = getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
```

For comparing orientation:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){...}
```