# Randomly Placing view in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development, and I am trying to place a view (`imageView` to be specific) in a random place inside of a fragment, but I'm having a lot of trouble. I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to find out how to do this, but I still can't figure it out.

So originally, I had the random position of the View thing working in a regular activity using this method:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    params.leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - button.getWidth());
    params.topMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - 2 * button.getHeight());
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But this doesn't work in a `Fragment` because I can't do `button.getWidth()`. So then I tried using the [ViewTreeObserver method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845197/android-get-fragment-width), but I really didn't understand what was going on and I couldn't get it to work for me.

Could someone please explain how I can randomly place a view inside of a fragment, without the view going outside of the boundaries of the fragment?

P.S. If someone just answers with "you should do some more research," please just understand that I have literally spent about 10 hours trying to figure this out, and have completely exhausted any ideas of how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I can't do button.getWidth()" - A view's width and height are not available until after it's been inflated. If you try to call `button.getWidth()` inside `onCreate` or `onCreateView`, it'll return `0` because the view has not yet been inflated.

Instead, try callung `button.getWidth()` in `onActivityCreated` or `onViewCreated`, which are callback methods that let you know when all the view's are good to go.

Comment: I tried that before but then I wasn't able to call getWindowManager(). Any tips with that? Additionally, would this method be finding the height and width of the whole screen or just the fragment?

Comment: calling `button.getwidth()` finds the width of the button. if possible, try to work with the sizes of the views you care about directly.  If you must find the size of the whole screen: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629675/get-screen-width-and-height-in-a-fragment)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. I got the size of the button, which is awesome. But now how do I get the size of the fragment? Because the metrics method gets the size of the screen.

Comment: just get the size of the top-level view (that is, the one that occupies the entire fragment).