# use getWindowManager with FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I have a class which extends `FragmentActivity`. I want to use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);` to get screen width and height

But `getWindowManager` gives an error `invalid method declaration , return type required`

Comment: Post the code where you are actually trying to use it, the snippet you posted looks ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629675/get-screen-width-and-height-in-a-fragment/11629766 or you can refer to these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833825/error-getting-window-size-on-android-the-method-getwindowmanager-is-undefined

Comment: I am not trying it in fragment, It is in FragmentActvity

Comment: If you want displayMetrics just call `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`

Comment: must follow to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this method.It will work properly
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);